# Azure pipeline stageList parameter to extend template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to pass stage list from azure pipeline shown below

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- master

extends:
  template: start_stage.yml
  parameters:
    cdstages:  
    - stage: secure_buildstage
      pool: Hosted VS2017
      jobs:
      - job: secure_buildjob
        steps:
        - bash: echo This happens before code 
          displayName: 'Base: Pre-build'
        - bash: echo Building
          displayName: 'Base: Build'

        - bash: echo This happens after code
          displayName: 'Base: Signing'

    - stage: secure_deploystage
      pool: Hosted VS2017
      jobs:
      - job: secure_deployjob
        steps:
        - bash: echo This happens before code 
          displayName: 'Base: Pre-build'
        - bash: echo Building
          displayName: 'Base: Build'

        - script: echo This happens after code
          displayName: 'Base: Signing'
```

to extend template shown below

```
parameters:
- name: cdstages # the name of the parameter is buildSteps
  type: stageList # data type is StepList
  default: [] # default value of buildSteps
stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.cdstages }}:
  - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:
    - ${{ each step in job.steps }}:
      - ${{ each pair in step }}:
          ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}:
            ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}       
          ${{ if eq(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}: 
            '${{ pair.value }}': error
```

The goal is to take stage list and validate if users are only running steps approved by firm's compliance team.

I'm getting error
[[image]][1

not sure why getting "task" error, there are no task keywords used anywhere.
Any help?

Comment: as per this learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/… a job array can be passed and then we can access both jobs and steps in extend template, then we should be able to access stage->job->steplist

Answer (score 2):

Based on my test , it seems that the stagelist in `start_stage.yml` doesn't support to add `each`directive to get  deeper content (e.g. job and steps).

When you use the stagelist, it could get the stage and use it for comparison.

For example:

```
parameters:
- name: cdstages # the name of the parameter is buildSteps
  type: stageList # data type is StepList
  default: [] # default value of buildSteps

stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.cdstages }}:
  - ${{ each pair in stage }}:
      ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'abc') }}:
        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}       
      ${{ if eq(pair.value, 'abc') }}: 
        '${{ pair.value }}': error
```

This Yaml template could work.

But when I add the `each` directive behind the stage to get the jobs. The jobs are is not available.

```
parameters:
- name: cdstages 
  type: stageList 
  default: [] 

stages:
- ${{ each stage in parameters.cdstages }}:
  - ${{ each job in stage.jobs }}:
    - ${{ each pair in job }}:
        ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'abc') }}:
          ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}       
        ${{ if eq(pair.value, 'abc') }}: 
          '${{ pair.value }}': error
```

[image: job issue]

According to your requirements, you need to get the build step and use it for comparison.

You could try to directly use the `steplist` type.

Here is an example about [steplist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template), you could refer to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We are planning to setup multistage yaml pipeline for development team and passing steplist at each job changes the experience for them. We have to analyze what they are running so we thought of using extend template check at agent pool level, is there any other way to see what user is trying to run right after they queue their build.

Comment: as per this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/templates?view=azure-devops#additional-steps      a job array can be passed and then we can access both jobs and steps in extend template, then we should be able to access stage->job->steplist